# how to use filter in query twice in django

Tags: django, database, model

I am trying to filter some data using this query,

```
get_members = PaymentDetails.objects.filter(participants_name=Participants.objects.filter(participants_name=Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)))
```

but I am getting this error The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing. My models looks like this

```
class Committee(models.Model):
    committee_creator = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    committee_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Participants(models.Model):
    participants_name = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participants_committee_name = models.ForeignKey(Committee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   
class PaymentDetails(models.Model):
    participants_name = models.ForeignKey(Participants, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participants_paid_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    participants_amount_paid = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this i will assume that you have `OneToOne` Relationship between `User` and `Profile`.

```
get_members = PaymentDetails.objects.filter(participants_name__participants_name_id = request.user.profile.pk)
```

Comment: I have two results in the database but it is only showing one of the user which is logged in,

Comment: @faizkhan you want to get for all users ? the code you showed was just for the current user.

Comment: I want to get all the users which are part of paymentdetails model

Comment: @faizkhan try this `PaymentDetails.objects.all().values_list('participants_name__participants_name__user',flat=True)`